# Unexpected cache in PHP class Cake PHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working in a Cake PHP 2.10 application, I have a PHP class called `CommissionsConsolidationReport` and I need to use the Cake PHP cache feature, but when trying to do `Cache::read()` and `Cache::write()` an error is thrown in my error.log saying "Unexpected Cache" despite using `App::uses('Cache')` at the top of my file.

What am I missing?

```php
<?php

App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility', 'Cache');

class CommissionsConsolidationReport
{
        /**
         * Get applications
         *
         * @return array
         */
        private function getApplications()
        {
                ClassRegistry::init('Cache');

                
                $result = Cache::read('newest_posts', 'long');
                if (!$result) {
                        $result = 'is set'
                        Cache::write('newest_posts', $result, 'long');
                }

                var_dump($result);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to [configure default cache engine](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class) or [custom cache engine](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/caching.html#creating-a-storage-engine-for-cache)